# Prevent Context from updating in Django

Tags: django

So my very little lack of django knowledge makes it a bit hard to explain exactly what's going on.I think specifically the lack of knowledge in regards to how this boilerplate/project/framework is set up makes it a bit hard for me explain the issue but I'll give it a try

I'm trying to render a Django Template with a given context. Now I manage to render the template but the context keeps updating itself. How do I make the template differentiate between the contexts ? or how do I prevent the context from updating itself ?

```
    def render_stateTree(self,request,temp_context):
        c = RequestContext(request, temp_context)
        # Create a response
        response = TemplateResponse(request, 'admin/StateTree.html', c)
        # Register the callback
        response.resolve_context(temp_context)
        # Return the response
        return response


    def get_urls(self):
        from django.conf.urls import patterns, url, include

        if settings.DEBUG:
            self.check_dependencies()

    def wrap(view, cacheable=False):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            return self.admin_view(view, cacheable)(*args, **kwargs)
        return update_wrapper(wrapper, view)

    # Admin-site-wide views.
    urlpatterns = patterns('',
        url(r'^$',
            wrap(self.index),
            name='index'),
        url(r'^logout/$',
            wrap(self.logout),
            name='logout'),
        url(r'^password_change/$',
            wrap(self.password_change, cacheable=True),
            name='password_change'),
        url(r'^password_change/done/$',
            wrap(self.password_change_done, cacheable=True),
            name='password_change_done'),
        url(r'^jsi18n/$',
            wrap(self.i18n_javascript, cacheable=True),
            name='jsi18n'),
        url(r'^r/(?P<content_type_id>\d+)/(?P<object_id>.+)/$',
            wrap(contenttype_views.shortcut),
            name='view_on_site'),
        url(r'^(?P<app_label>\w+)/$',
            wrap(self.app_index),
            name='app_list')
    )



    # Add in each model's views.
    for model, model_admin in six.iteritems(self._registry):
        urlpatterns += patterns('',
            url(r'^%s/%s/' % (model._meta.app_label, model._meta.model_name),
                include(model_admin.urls))
        )
        #urlpatterns += patterns('',url(r'statetree', lambda x : render(x,'admin/StateTree.html')))+static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_URL)
        #urlpatterns += patterns('',url(r'WIL_sde_states.txt',lambda x : 5)+ 
        urlpatterns += patterns('',url(r'statetree', lambda x : TemplateResponse(x,'admin/StateTree.html', context, current_app=self.name)))+static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_URL+'stateTreeDocs')    



    state_tree_directory = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__)),'admin','static','stateTreeDocs')



    for filename in os.listdir(state_tree_directory):
        # context_txt[filename] = {
        #     'textfile' : 'stateTreeDocs/'+filename
        # }
        **c = {'textfile' : 'stateTreeDocs/'+filename}
        #urlpatterns += patterns('',url(r''+filename, lambda x : TemplateResponse(x,'admin/StateTree.html', c, current_app=self.name)))+static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_URL+'stateTreeDocs')
        urlpatterns += patterns('',url(r''+filename, lambda x : self.render_stateTree(x, c)))+static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_URL+'stateTreeDocs')**

        #print context_txt[filename]['textfile']


    return urlpatterns
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'updating itself'? Do you want to use an `if:` statement?

Comment: Hi thanks for the response. So in my understanding each template should be rendered with a different context if you look at the for loop at the bottom of the code.

context 'c' is assigned a value and it is then passed to a template and rendered.

The next iteration of the for-loop the variable 'c' has a new value and is passed to a template and rendered.

For some reason, the context is the same across all four templates. Meaning that only the variable 'c' is always equal the last iteration of the for-loop.

I hope this clarifies things a bit

Comment: Each template does not need a different context, but a template can only be passed a single context. How many templates are you using?

Comment: ah that explains it, I only have a single HTML document/template that I'm trying to fill with different contexts. How would I got about this ?

Comment: ah that might explain it. I have 4 different URLS, each URL but each URL is assigned the same template/HTML file. How do I get around this issue ? How to I make it so that each individual URL has its own context ? even though the templates are the same

Comment: You need to render all requests for a particular page within the same `Context`. Like: `c = {'textfile': 'stateTreeDocs/'+fileName, 'textfile2': 'stateTreeDocs2/'+filename}`